# Rails on Heroku: session variables nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, heroku

I've done a lot of research and can't find any similar questions/answers, so I appreciate the help.

My app is working great locally, but **when I push to Heroku, it chokes on my session variables**. Specifically, it throws a NoMethodError for nil:NilClass when I try to access attributes of the object held in the session. I've narrowed it down to the session after switching to params and having success. However, I'd prefer using the session as it keeps my code a little cleaner.

I've poked around and it seems to be happening with every session object. The quick context is that I create a new charge, then a new organization, and then associate the charge with the organization.

The protocol is *https* (this is a checkout page) and these calls are happening asynchronously  via jQuery, though I'm not sure if that matters. Rails 3.2. Cedar/Postgres on Heroku. Sqlite3/Thin locally.

What's happening to the session on Heroku?

### production.rb

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_my_app_session', :domain => :all
```

### application_controller.rb

```
...

helper_method :current_charge
def current_charge
  @_current_charge ||= session[:current_charge_id] &&
  Charge.find_by_id(session[:current_charge_id])
end

...
```

### charges_controller.rb

```
def create
  @charge = Charge.new(params[:charge])
  if @charge.save
    session[:current_charge_id] = @charge.id
  ...
end
```

### organizations_controller.rb

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(params[:organization])
  if @organization.save
    @charge = current_charge
    @charge.organization_id = @organization.id
    @charge.save!
  ...
end
```

### Cedar log (thrown on organizations_controller.rb)

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `organization_id=' for nil:NilClass):
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a record using `new`, the record doesn't persist to the database until it is saved, and no id is assigned to a record until it is persisted.

In your code:

```
def create
  @charge = Charge.new(params[:charge])
  session[:current_charge_id] = @charge.id
  ...
end
```

`@charge.id` is nil at this point, and therefore won't have an id.  You'll need to use `create` in your charges_controller.rb to give the record an id:

```
def create
  @charge = Charge.create(params[:charge])
  session[:current_charge_id] = @charge.id
  ...
end
```

Or use your existing code and add a save before setting the session key:

```
def create
  @charge = Charge.new(params[:charge])

  @charge.save

  session[:current_charge_id] = @charge.id
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. I realized that issue and fixed it, but as I mentioned, this is happening to all session objects. It is working locally but not on Heroku. Any other ideas?

Comment: My only other thought would be to change your helper method to lookup `current_charge_id` as a string and not a symbol...  I've run into that before where the session hash doesn't have indifferent access, so it converts symbols to strings when it sets an attribute, and then it's only accessible via the string.  Make sense?

Comment: Makes sense, but no luck :(